# How to pass a function to lower widget

Tags: flutter, dart

```
child: DismissiblePage(
        direction: DismissDirection.down,
        onDismiss: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        child: InstagramStorySwipe(
          initialPage: index,
          children: List.generate(
            snapshot.data?.data?.data?.user?.feedReelsTray
                ?.edgeReelsTrayToReel?.edges?.length,
            (index) => ViewStoryScreen(
              // changePage: ,
              index: index,
              edges: snapshot.data.data.data.user.feedReelsTray
                  .edgeReelsTrayToReel.edges,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Here i have a method in InstagramStorySwipe which i need to call with the ViewStoryScreen

Edit: code
also the whole thing is inside another class so i cant call InstagramSwipes method

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "method in InstagramStorySwipe" is called `myMethod`, you can add a parameter to the constructor of `ViewStoryScreen` like so:

```dart
class ViewStoryScreen extends StatelessWidget { // or StatefulWidget
  ViewStoryScreen({
    this.changePage,
    this.index,
    this.edges,
    this.myMethod,
  });

  /// The method passed by the parent
  final void Function() myMethod; // Change the signature of the function depending on myMethod

  final String changePage;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: the parent InstagramStorySwipe is actually called here, is there a way to pass the method from parent to child when i just called the parent

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. If the parent is `InstagramStorySwipe` and the child is `ViewStoryScreen`, my code actually passes a method from the parent to the child... Could you share the full code of `InstagramStorySwipe` and `ViewStoryScreen` and let us know which method you want to pass?

Comment: child: InstagramStorySwipe() is actually called there right inside another class .

Comment: `DismissiblePage(
            
            child: InstagramStorySwipe(
              initialPage: index,
              children: List.generate(
                snapshot.data?.data?.data?.user?.feedReelsTray
                    ?.edgeReelsTrayToReel?.edges?.length,
                (index) => ViewStoryScreen(
                  changePage: ,
                  index: index,
                  edges: snapshot.data.data.data.user.feedReelsTray
                      .edgeReelsTrayToReel.edges,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),`

Comment: That's not very readable by a mere mortal like me. Could you update your question and format the code?

Comment: i did changes in the question